# WPF: Use property field value in ComboBox instead of the object name

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

My combobox is bound with google search results.

```
<ComboBox
    Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
    IsEditable="True"
    IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding GoogleSuggest.SuggestedQueries}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding GoogleSuggest.SelectedQuery}"
    >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                
                <Image Source={Binding IconPath, Converter={StaticResource IconPathToImageSource} Width="32" Height="32" />
                
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Query}" Margin="0,8" FontSize="24" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding URL}" Margin="0,8" FontSize="16" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

My Model looks like this

```
public class Model_SuggestedQueries : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _Query = string.Empty;
    public string Query
    {
        get { return _Query; }
        set
        {
            if (_Query != value)
            {
                _Query = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged("Query");
            }
        }
    }

    private int _Index = 0;
    public int Index
    {
        get { return _Index; }
        set
        {
            if (_Index != value)
            {
                _Index = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged("Index");
            }
        }
    }
    
    private string _URL = 0;
    public string URL
    {
        get { return _URL; }
        set
        {
            if (_URL != value)
            {
                _URL = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged("URL");
            }
        }
    }
    
    private string _Icon = 0;
    public string Icon
    {
        get { return _Icon; }
        set
        {
            if (_Icon != value)
            {
                _Icon = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged("Icon");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I make a selection, the .Text field looked like this.

[image]

How can I show the "Query" value instead of the object name?

Comment: Try use `<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Query" ... />`. That help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to add the **DisplayMemberPath** attribute to your ComboBox Control ?

```
 <ComboBox
        Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
        IsEditable="True"
        IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding GoogleSuggest.SuggestedQueries}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding GoogleSuggest.SelectedQuery}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Query"
        >
```

If it doesn't work you may try to override the **ToString()** method of your **Model_SuggestedQueries** class.

Comment: Overriding the ToString() method works. DisplayMemberPath does not due to ItemTemplate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add `TextSearch.TextPath="Query"` to your ComboBox markup.

See [MSDN Textsearch.Textpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textsearch.textpath.aspx)

Comment: This works as well! It's more XAMLity than overriding ToString().

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an easier way to achieve your goal,try this:
**Just override the ToString() function of your class"Model_SuggestedQueries"**
:p